# Having errors writing a Cypher query that gets the destination of a bus

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a Cypher query that handles the following:

```
MATCH (a:station{name:"modakeke"})<-[:ORIGIN]-(b:bus)
RETURN b
```

The above query lists all the buses that originated from the station called modakeke.

I am trying to write a Cypher query that provides a list of all the stations, all buses that originated from modakeke stopped(Destination)

The relationships I access to  include

```
[:ORIGIN]  (which means the bus originated from)
[:DESTINATION]  (where the bus ended its journey
```

this is what I did so far:

```
MATCH (a:station{name:"modakeke"})<-[:ORIGIN]-(b:bus)->[:DESTINATION]-(a)
RETURN a.name
```

I keep getting errors with the above query

`Bus A`

`Bus B`

`Station: Modakeke`

`Station : Ife`

`Station: Ibadan`

`[:Origin]`
`[:destination]`

`Bus A [:Origin] from Station: Modakeke`

`Bus A has [:Destination] I want to Know which Station Bus A is going`

Comment: please give us sample data to work on, show us your error and put the expected result(s). Thanks.

Comment: its a bit complicated on how to get sample data, but I have included more informaton

Comment: Neo4j node labels and relationship types are case sensitive.  I see you are mixing case on both node labels (station versus Station) ORIGIN and Origin, and for relationships DESTINATION/destination/Destination, which should cause an error, except when they match what you've stored in the database.  You can view your meta model several ways,  I prefer to use call apoc.meta.graph(), if you run that, please share the metamodel for your graph, that will help us, help you.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow `->` is always going from the outside of a relationship pattern `[]`.

This is valid :

- `<-[:DESTINATION]-`
- `-[:DESTINATION]->`

This is not valid ( taken from your query) :

- `->[:DESTINATION]`

Your query should be :

```
MATCH (a:station{name:"modakeke"})<-[:ORIGIN]-(b:bus)-[:DESTINATION]->(a)
RETURN a.name
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the response, but id did not bring any result